# Is there a word that describes a person who constantly exaggerates?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Is there a word that describes a person who constantly exaggerates? Exaggerating both facts and their emotions?

Edit: the word should have a negative connotation, as if you are criticizing someone for exaggerating too much.

Comment: The word *alarmist* will work in some contexts, basically where they're overstating a threat.

Comment: I love this question and it deserves a million upvotes...

Answer (score 11):

[*Exaggerator*](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.com/definitions/exaggerator) and [*overstater*](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.com/definitions/overstater?cx=partner-pub-0939450753529744%3Av0qd01-tdlq&cof=FORID%3A9&ie=UTF-8&q=overstater&sa=Search#906) are both English words that fit your meaning.

Answer (score 5):

How about [**histrionic**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/histrionic)? Or [**drama queen**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=drama%20queen)?

Comment: 'Histrionic' refers more to character and style rather than speech right? I was thinking of a word more relevant to exaggeration in speech hmm..

Answer (score 4):

How about braggart? ~ "  A vain bragger, one who brags much."

http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/22483?redirectedFrom=braggart#eid

Comment: Only when exaggerating own positive qualities. You won't call a braggart one who says "I'm utterly hopeless" about being less than perfect.

Answer (score 4):

*Bullshitter* comes to mind, although it is potentially offensive.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Good answer, although you may want to provide a reference and re-write in a less informal style. See [How to Answer Questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: Know what? Where it doesn't give offense, bullshitter is the most accurate word, and the one most common in speech.

Comment: @user1678063 could you please rewrite your comment in a more formal style - this is a very serious forum, where we all have to be dead formal.

Answer (score 3):

You might try *Munchausen*, after the fictional (and fiction-creating) German Baron.  Be careful, though; the word has been taken up by the medical profession to describe somebody who constantly fantasises or lives in a dream world, which is stronger than the original meaning, and probably stronger than you're looking for.

Comment: To avoid the medical connotation one could refer to the person as a "Baron Munchausen".

Answer (score 3):

*Exaggerator* works fine, but if you want something fancier you could try on *hyperbolist*.

Comment: 'hyperbolic' is an existing word (an adjective though) but it might be misunderstood (being too well associated with mathematics).

Comment: Hyperbolist is more of a neutral word right? I am looking for something that has a negative connotation, as if you are criticizing someone for exaggerating too much in speech.

Comment: @darrentnh: It reads as sarcastic praise to me, which is probably more subtle than you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about [Coproglot](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Coproglot&defid=2654057) ?

Comment: This word is not standard English right?

Comment: Define standard English. This is urban dictionary aka dictionary of slang.

Comment: "coproglot" should be avoided, since the hearer may think it is related to other words with prefix "copro-".

Comment: @GEdgar, it's probably the whole point. If "polyglot" means you speak many languages, coproglot means you speak shit.

Answer (score 0):

You could call him a "Commander McBragg"

McBragg is a a cartoon character that tells stories in his English club about his many exploits that are hard to believe.  Here are a examples and a link to a Wikepedia description:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4roxM8hUMk

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nkZzLUvuLLU

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commander_McBragg