# Someone who is a combo of a liar, an exaggerater, and have a tendency to construct stories

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Is there a term for such a person?

*Background:*

Someone who is a pathological liar, an overt exaggerator. He would want to take center-stage, makes up stories to capture interest, and applies his stated qualities in positive as well as negative interactions.

Such a person, I believe borderlines personality disorder.

But can we summarize him in a word?

Some words that [I looked up](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70830/is-there-a-word-that-describes-a-person-who-constantly-exaggerates) appear to have different connotations:

- Exaggerator
- braggart

Comment: For some reason, the first word that comes to mind is _politician_ …

Comment: Fantasist.....?

Comment: Try [topper](http://search.dilbert.com/comic/Topper). (More seriously: *blowhard*).

Comment: A "fabulist" or a "confabulator".

Comment: "prevaricator!", "Sociopath!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***mythomaniac***

> *mythomania (Psychiatry)*  the tendency to lie, exaggerate, or relate incredible imaginary adventures as if they had really happened, occurring in some mental disorders
>
> <sup>http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mythomaniac</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As @ermanen points out, the one-word that matches your description would be :

[Mythomane](http://dictionary.reference.com/wordoftheday/archive/2014/10/15.html) , noun, meaning- a person with a strong or irresistible *propensity* for **fantasizing, lying, or exaggerating**.

Answer (score 1):

I usually call such people ***blowhards***.

From [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/blowhard):

> ***blowhard***: *A person who blusters and boasts in an unpleasant way*

From [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/blowhard):

> ***blowhard***: *someone who talks too much about themselves or the things they have achieved*

From [Vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/blowhard):

> ***blowhard***
>
> *A blowhard is someone who always brags or boasts about himself. If you get stuck sitting next to your blowhard cousin at the family holiday dinner, you may wish he didn't think he was quite so amazing.*
>
> *Blowhard is an informal word describing someone who can't stop talking about themselves or their accomplishments, real or imagined. You might know a blowhard at school, at work, or even in your family. And usually everyone knows at least one blowhard sports fan, who during the game can't stop talking about the unprecedented greatness of his favorite team or player.*

Alternatives include *braggart*, *windbag*, and *[topper](http://search.dilbert.com/comic/Topper)*:

[image: Dilbert comic of "The Topper"]

Comment: *Blowhard* does not imply liar, especially pathological liar.

Comment: @Drew see third cite: "Someone who can't stop talking about their accomplishments, *real or imagined*".

Comment: 1. "3rd cite" does not characterize the question as a whole. 2. Bragging about one's imagined accomplishments does not make one a liar. (Yes, it means that something the person says is an untruth, but saying untruths now and then does not make someone a liar.)